# Capturing batch file user prompt in python subprocess

Tags: python, batch-file, python-3.x, cmd, subprocess

I am trying to execute a batch file from a python script, using the python script as the 'front end' to the batch file, as it were. (It's a long story, and one that isn't relevant.)

However, the batch file includes a challenge-and-respond in it, something like:

```
:star
set /p var=Enter The Value:%=%
@echo %var%
if %var%!=%other_var% goto :star
```

So basically, it prompts the user for input, then checks if the input is correct, and if not prompts the user against.

How do I read the prompt in my python script, and then check if the script prompted me again (IE. wrong input), or if it passed? I'm currently using subprocess' Popen constructor, and I've tried a `.stdout.readline()` loop, printing each line, to which the prompt simply doesn't show up. (The loop successfully catches and reads all the lines prior, but not the prompt itself.)

I've tried a `.communicate(input="foo\n")`, and this technically works, in that the batch file will successfully pass if foo is the expected variable. If not, it just locks up and waits forever.

I've tried writing to stdin, and that just simply locks up with little indication of what's going on.

How should I proceed?

EDIT:
Continuing to experiment, I tried to open a cmd.exe instance, and then run commands through that.

```
import subprocess as sp

p = sp.Popen(["cmd.exe"], stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout = sp.PIPE, shell=True)

print("RUN")

# print(p.communicate(input=b"echo HELLO WORLD\n"))

for i in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print(str(i))
    p.stdin.write(b'echo HELLO WORLD!')
```

The commented out `.communicate` works, but again, it blocks until the process finishes, which is not really an option for the challenge-and-response thing. The `.readline` and `.stdin` interfaces, however, do not. It prints:

```
b'Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]\r\n'
b'Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.\r\n'
b'\r\n'
```

And then blocks there until I terminate the cmd.exe instance.

Any ideas?

EDIT2:
I would love to have something like pexpect for Windows, however, the only ones I can find seem to have been last updated a few years ago, and not fully functional on Windows 7 or higher.

Comment: you could try: `for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''): process.stdin.write("foo\n" if random.random() < .99 else "other\n")` It may fail if there are buffering issues.

Comment: It *does* fail. To be honest, I'm not very sure what's happening on the batch file side; batch files are not my thing. Additionally, `.write('foo\n')` fails with `str does not support buffer interface`. It has to be `b'foo\n'`, a byte string.

Comment: @Fimagzen: 1. try it with the batch file. I have no idea where batch files print their prompt (they may print directly to the console, `putwch`) and where they accept their input (`getwch`). Passing commands to cmd.exe is not the same thing as accepting input in a batch file. Though it also may fail 2. You must specify [tag:python-3.x] tag if you expect Python 3 answers. 3. Why would you use `shell=True`?

Comment: 1. I have tried it with both cmd.exe and the batch file, to no avail. 2. Noted, I have done so. 3. I tried it both with and without `shell=True` just in case it made a difference. As I said, I'm not really very sure of what's happening on the batch file side.

Comment: 1 It is *very* helpful to include *relevant* code that tries to run the batch file and drop everything else. 2. If you've tried [`winpexpect`](https://bitbucket.org/geertj/winpexpect/wiki/Home) or [`wexpect`](http://sage.math.washington.edu/home/goreckc/sage/wexpect/) then specify how exactly they failed.